# How to hide a floatingActionButton after insert data flutter?

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, flutter-layout, sqflite

I use sqflite for flutter database management. In particular, I would like the user to enter the data only once and therefore I would need to hide and disable the button only once the data has been entered. How can I do?

**Home Page**, where is the button

```
class Casa extends StatefulWidget {
 static const routeName = '/';
 @override
 _CasaState createState() => _CasaState();
}
class _CasaState extends State<Casa> {
DataRepository _repository;     
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _repository = SqlRepository();
  }
 
  @override
  void dispose() async {
    await _repository.closeDB();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void getNewItem(BuildContext context) async {
    Attivita newItem =
        await Navigator.pushNamed<Attivita>(context, AddItemScreen.routeName);
    
    if (newItem != null) {
      await _repository.add(newItem);
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

 void switchAndUpdate(Attivita item) async {
    await _repository.put(item.id, item);
    setState(() {});
  }

void delete(Attivita item) async {
    await _repository.delete(item.id);
    setState(() {});
  }


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue[900],
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
         child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.lightBlue[900],),
         backgroundColor: Colors.white,
         onPressed: () {
           getNewItem(context);
         },
       ),


    body: 
    FutureBuilder<List<Attivita>>(
        
        future: _repository.getAll(),
        
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Attivita>> snapshot) {
          return ListView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            itemCount: snapshot.data == null ? 0 : snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Dismissible(
                key: UniqueKey(),
                background: DecoratedBox(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment(-0.9, 00),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.delete,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                direction: DismissDirection.startToEnd,
                onDismissed: (direction) {
                 Attivita item = snapshot.data[index];
                 snapshot.data.removeAt(index);
                 delete(item);

                },
                child: Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  
                  title: Text(snapshot.data[index].nome, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue[900]),),
                  
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, DettaglioScreen.routeName, arguments: snapshot.data[index]);

                  },
                  onLongPress: () {
                    switchAndUpdate(snapshot.data[index]);
                  },
                ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      )

     ),
   );
 }
}
```

so i have to add some details, because it is written that "it looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"

Comment: What have you accomplished so far?

Put your codes here please.

Answer (score 0):

To check if user put so data you can use:

1. Use sharedPreferences and store bool value if user entered data.
2. On initState check if database contains data if yes it means user put some data and you can hide button.

I don't use Sqlite in flutter but I think you can use

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> result;
result = await db.query(tableName);
isNotData = result.isEmpty;
```

Or something similar :) You can do it

Choose one way and store bool value eg. in bool isNotData

When you will have bool value about data you can write:

In _CasaState above initState: bool isNotData;

and in Scaffold in floatingActionButton property:

```
Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Material App Bar'),
    ),
    floatingActionButton: isNotData
        ? FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        : null,
    body: Center(
      
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: How i  check if database contains data?

Comment: @EdoardoDellaSeta check my answer again